# Is there any ffmpeg option to rescale too fast/slow subtitles?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I found subtitles to an old movie but no one fits to it correctly. I found a delay option like:

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset 2 -i subtitles.srt -c copy subtitles_delayed.srt
```

which could fit it at current frame, but then I realized it's too early on the beginning (eg 2 seconds) and too late on the endings (3 seconds). Can I simply rescale it giving times of first and last subtitle using those scripts??

Comment: Maybe. But in my experience, you just need to search for a subtitle that better fits the vide you have. Anything else is headache inducing if you ask me. I recommend poking around [OpenSubtitles](https://www.opensubtitles.org/) and trying out a few different subtitles for each film. At least one should fit your video’s timing.

Comment: Thanks for response. What I learned for now is that I tried all 4 I found in the whole net because it's quite rare movie. I think I'll try to write a script for this - it's easier than it looks. There's also some VLC player synchro - never used but they say it's easy.

Comment: Why not simply use a program like [SubtitleEdit](https://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit)? From memory it has options to shift or change timestamps across files.

Comment: @Peter.k Please don’t [post an answer as an “EDIT” to the question](https://superuser.com/posts/1774379/revisions) as you did; I removed it. While a bit esoteric, it seems useful enough and should be posted as its own answer which you can then check off as such after a few days.